# is log(n!) equivalent to nlogn? (Big O notation)

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

In my book there is a multiple choice question:

> What is the big O notation of the following function:
>   n^log(2) +log(n^n) + nlog(n!)

I know that log(n!) belongs to O(nlogn), But I read online that they are equivalent. how is log(n!) the same thing as saying nlogn?
how is:
log(n!) = logn + log(n-1) + ... + log2 + log1 
equivalent to nlogn?

Comment: It is only *asymptotically* equivalent to `n log n`. [Stirling's thereom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) states that `ln (n!) ≈  n ln n - n + O(log n)`, and of course the asymptotically largest term dominates. You can also prove this by bounding it from above and below.

Answer (score 9):

Let `n/2` be the quotient of the integer division of `n` by `2`. We have:

```
log(n!) =  log(n) + log(n-1) + ... + log(n/2) + log(n/2 - 1) + ... + log(2) + log(1)
        >= log(n/2) + log(n/2) + ... + log(n/2) + log(n/2 - 1) + ... + log(2)
        >= (n/2)log(n/2) + (n/2)log(2)
        >= (n/2)(log(n) -log(2) + log(2))
        =  (n/2)log(n)
```

then

```
n log(n) <= 2log(n!) = O(log(n!))
```

and `n log(n) = O(log(n!))`. Conversely,

```
log(n!) <= log(n^n) = n log(n)
```

and `log(n!) = O(n log(n))`.