# Why the complexity of this algorithm is O(n log(n)))?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I have a multi-set S with positive numbers where I want to partition it into K  subsets such that the difference between the sum of partitions is minimized. one simple heuristics approach to the above problem is the greedy algorithm, which iterates through the set of numbers sorted in descending order, assigning each of them to whichever subset has the smaller sum of the numbers. My question is why time complexity of this greedy algorithm is O(nlog(n))?

Comment: O(n log n) is what it costs to sort the list of numbers.

Comment: Thanks. Is this sorting look like the merge sort? I have a for loop over the sorted list so it is log(n) complexity. But I don't understand why finding the smallest sum of the numbers has O(logn) complexity.

Comment: It doesn't matter what sorting algorithm you use.  The best ones take O(n log n).  Finding the smallest sum of the numbers takes O(log K), but you have to do that n times, so O(n log K) all together.  See @trincot's answer

Answer (score 0):

Determining *"whichever subset has the smaller sum of the numbers"* will take logarithmic time on the current number of subsets. You would need to implement some sort of priority queue or heap for doing this efficiently with such a time complexity. In a worst case your number of sets will be O(), and so you get the following search time complexities as each input value is processed:

O(log(1) + log(2) + log(3) + ... + log)

= [O(log!)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Logarithmic_identities)

= [O(log)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52519329/is-logn-equivalent-to-nlogn-big-o-notation)